# Staged programming - Jake Bolewski's speech

Tags: julia

**Version**: from Julia v0.4 onwards (I use 0.5.0-dev+433 (2015-09-29 15:39 UTC))

**Reference**: [Jake Bolewski: Staged programming in Julia](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KAN8zbM659o)

**Problem**: After watching Jakes Bolewski's speech regarding `StaticVec` I did not catch the idea behind the example with `length` function.

```
julia> type StaticVec{T,N}
        vals::Vector{T}
       end

julia> StaticVec(T,vals...) = StaticVec{T,length(vals)}([vals...])
StaticVec{T,N}

julia> v= StaticVec(Float64,1,2,3)
StaticVec{Float64,3}([1.0,2.0,3.0])
```

Non-staged `length`:

```
julia> function Base.length{T,N}(v::StaticVec{T,N}) 
        N
       end
length (generic function with 58 methods)

julia> code_llvm(length, (StaticVec{Float64,3},))

define i64 @julia_length_21889(%jl_value_t*) {
top:
  ret i64 3
}
```

and staged `length` version

```
julia> @generated function Base.length{T,N}(v::StaticVec{T,N}) 
        :(N)
       end
length (generic function with 58 methods)

julia> code_llvm(length, (StaticVec{Float64,3},))

define i64 @julia_length_21888(%jl_value_t*) {
top:
  ret i64 3
}
```

give the same llvm code.

I suppose I understand the idea behind staged programming, but in this particular example I don't understand the intention of the speaker. Could anyone explain it to me?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That example was probably not the best choice since, as you point out, it doesn't require generated functions at all. Jiahao Chen recently wrote a [blog post](https://medium.com/@acidflask/smoothing-data-with-julia-s-generated-functions-c80e240e05f3) with an excellent example of using a generated function to do efficient data smoothing. Here's a similar bit of code to his that improves efficiency even further by peeling off `M` loop iterations at the front and back, thereby avoiding branches in the main loop body:

```
immutable SavitzkyGolayFilter{M,N} end

wrapL(i, n) = ifelse(1 ≤ i, i, i + n)
wrapR(i, n) = ifelse(i ≤ n, i, i - n)

@generated function smooth!{M,N}(
    ::Type{SavitzkyGolayFilter{M,N}},
    data::AbstractVector,
    smoothed::AbstractVector,
)
    # compute filter coefficients from the Jacobian
    J = Float64[(i-M-1)^(j-1) for i = 1:2M+1, j = 1:N+1]
    e₁ = [1; zeros(N)]
    C = J' \ e₁

    # generate code to evaluate filter on data matrix
    pre  = :(for i = 1:$M end)
    main = :(for i = $(M+1):n-$M end)
    post = :(for i = n-$(M-1):n end)
    for loop in (pre, main, post)
        body = loop.args[2].args
        push!(body, :(x = $(C[M+1]) * data[i]))
        for j = reverse(1:M)
            idx = loop !== pre ? :(i-$j) : :(wrapL(i-$j,n))
            push!(body, :(x += $(C[M+1-j]) * data[$idx]))
        end
        for j = 1:M
            idx = loop !== post ? :(i+$j) : :(wrapR(i+$j,n))
            push!(body, :(x += $(C[M+1+j]) * data[$idx]))
        end
        push!(body, :(smoothed[i] = x))
    end
    quote
        n = length(data)
        n == length(smoothed) || throw(DimensionMismatch())
        @inbounds $pre; @inbounds $main; @inbounds $post
        return smoothed
    end
end

smooth{S<:SavitzkyGolayFilter,T}(::Type{S}, data::AbstractVector{T}) =
    smooth!(S, data, Vector{typeof(1.0*one(T))}(length(data)))
```

The code generated for `smooth(SavitzkyGolayFilter{3,4}, rand(1000))`, for example, is the following:

```
n = length(data)
n == length(smoothed) || throw(DimensionMismatch())
@inbounds for i = 1:3
    x =   0.5670995670995674   * data[i]
    x +=  0.02164502164502159  * data[wrapL(i - 3, n)]
    x += -0.1298701298701297   * data[wrapL(i - 2, n)]
    x +=  0.32467532467532445  * data[wrapL(i - 1, n)]
    x +=  0.32467532467532473  * data[i + 1]
    x += -0.12987012987013022  * data[i + 2]
    x +=  0.021645021645021724 * data[i + 3]
    smoothed[i] = x
end
@inbounds for i = 4:n-3
    x =   0.5670995670995674   * data[i]
    x +=  0.02164502164502159  * data[i - 3]
    x += -0.1298701298701297   * data[i - 2]
    x +=  0.32467532467532445  * data[i - 1]
    x +=  0.32467532467532473  * data[i + 1]
    x += -0.12987012987013022  * data[i + 2]
    x +=  0.021645021645021724 * data[i + 3]
    smoothed[i] = x
end
@inbounds for i = n-2:n
    x =   0.5670995670995674   * data[i]
    x +=  0.02164502164502159  * data[i - 3]
    x += -0.1298701298701297   * data[i - 2]
    x +=  0.32467532467532445  * data[i - 1]
    x +=  0.32467532467532473  * data[wrapR(i + 1, n)]
    x += -0.12987012987013022  * data[wrapR(i + 2, n)]
    x +=  0.021645021645021724 * data[wrapR(i + 3, n)]
    smoothed[i] = x
end
return smoothed
```

As you might imagine, this generates very efficient machine code. I hope that clears up the concept of generated functions somewhat.

Comment: Thank you Stefan. Although your example is pretty elaborate and I prefer example from the documentation, nevertheless your answer has confirmed my prediction.